# Access bluetooth RFCOMM through android terminal

Tags: linux, android, bluetooth, serial-port

I would like to access to RFCOMM to set up a bluetooth virtual serial port on my Android device using the terminal.
I do have root permissions on my android device. 
When I type "rfcomm" in the terminal, I receive a message saying "rfcomm: not found". It seems I do not have an application rfcomm in my system. Where do I find that? Did I miss any other command? Unfortunately I am not used to work with linux frameworks...

Comment: Please add the Linux Distro you are using... it can help to locate the command request. BTW did you started the bluetooth service? `sudo service bluetooth start` ? With `which rfcomm` it should answer `/usr/bin/rfcomm`.

Comment: I am using Android 4.4.2.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. I thought you want to connect from a Linux Terminal to Android via _bluetooth_. Forget it. BTW [give it a look, references too](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33937/bluetooth-usb-on-android/33955#33955)

Comment: No Probs! btw any suggestions?